# manipulating UIScrollView height to add another UIView above it

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, height

I have a UIScrollView in which I am adding a subview which is a TimeLineView(a UIView).For the purpose of displaying; initially I just did the same and the TimeLineView got displayed without any problem. But now I want to have a UIView just above the UIScrollView where I can display some information about the the timeline.

Do I need to decrease the height of the UIScrollView so that the UIView gets fit on the space above it? If yes, How would I do that?

If there's another way...then please let me know.
All my initial implementations are as follows :

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) TimeLineView *timelineView;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize scrollView = scrollView;
@synthesize timelineView = timelineView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self prepareCustomView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{    
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        [self prepareCustomView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareCustomView {
    // Initialization code

    // Add main scroll view
[self addSubview:self.scrollView];

    // Add timeline view inside scrollview
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.timelineView];


}


- (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!scrollView) {
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, TOP_BAR_HEIGHT, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-TOP_BAR_HEIGHT-FOOTER_HEIGHT)];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width,TIMELINE_HEIGHT);
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
        scrollView.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = TRUE;
    }
    return scrollView;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I dont think so that you will be required to set the height of the UIView to fit in the scroll view. Please check the height of the UIView in the Interface Builder.

Click on the Application Frame.
Open the Attribute Inspector.
Check if status bar is none or not.

If not then set it to none. 

Check the value in the size inspector.
Set the height accordingly.

I hope this might help a bit.

Comment: thanks for reply first :)
but what I want is another UIView above the UIScrollView that I have implemented. Initially the scrollview occupied the full screen of the iphone simulator. Now I just want another UIView above it.

Comment: are you adding the UIView programatically.

Comment: ya..I am adding the UIView programmatically.

Comment: then yes you would have to manage the height manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to change y-axis and decrease the height of scrollview by the height of your UIView.You have to change the frame of your scrollview as follows if the scrollview is just below UIView:

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, UIViewFrame.size.height+UIViewFrame.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-TOP_BAR_HEIGHT-FOOTER_HEIGHT-UIViewFrame.size.height)];

where UIViewFrame is the frame of your UIView.